# How to use find/findOne outside of a helper function

Tags: angularjs, meteor, angular-meteor

I am trying to use a findOne statement to access a document from a collection, within a transform function.

```
  this.helpers({
    posts: function () {
      return Posts.find(this.getReactively('filter'), {sort: {createdAt: -1}, transform: function (doc) {
        var restaurant = Restaurants.findOne(doc.rest_id);
          doc.restaurant = restaurant.name;
          doc.neighborhood = restaurant.neighborhood;
        return doc;
      }});
    }
  });
```

The problem is that the call on findOne returns nothing (undefined). Similarly, using find.fetch() returns an empty Array.

After troubleshooting, I find that running find or findOne anywhere in my code except directly as a helper (i.e. return Posts.find() works fine) returns nothing. I've read that the client may not have finished subscribing to the data at this point, but nothing ever shows up on the client side.

Running the same Restaurants.find or findOne works fine on the Console, returning the expected documents.

Am I trying to do something not supported by angular-meteor? Are the find functions only supported within the context of a helper?

Comment: MongoDB is a document based database. In such database, you would like to have `restaurant` and `neighborhood` properties directly defined in `Posts` collection.

Comment: _"nothing ever shows up on the client side"_ or _"Running the same Restaurants.find or findOne works fine on the Console"_..? If the first is true, then you are not publishing data. If the latter is true, then you are trying to access this data before it is ready.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the part that you are missing here is that the `transform` function is being called by Mongo (i.e. in the Mongo call): this is not a callback function.

So, you need to fetch your documents, then findOne for each fetched document.

```
this.helpers({
    posts: function () {
      var my_posts = Posts.find(this.getReactively('filter'), {sort: {createdAt: -1}).fetch();
      my_posts.forEach(function (doc) {
        var restaurant = Restaurants.findOne(doc.rest_id);
          doc.restaurant = restaurant.name;
          doc.neighborhood = restaurant.neighborhood;
        return doc;
      }
    });        
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much, works flawlessly. I've been stuck on this for an embarrassing amount of time, I totally did not pick up on the callback issue.